# Closing popup window using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page with a button. When I press the button a popup window appears. In the popup window I have a '**Close**' button and when I press it, the popup windows should be closed and the main page must remain as is.

How can I close the popup window when I press the button?

Comment: Show your work and tell people what have you tried so far..

Comment: You have given no information to indicate how you are creating the popup window. How do you expect us to give you answer when you do not provide us with any useful information?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily have to be done server-side (i.e., in your C# code). Instead, this could be handled with some quick JavaScript on your view (cshtml, aspx, ascx, or html).

If you're using the ASP.NET controls:

```
<asp:Button id="MyButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:window.close(); return false;" />
```

If you're just using a regular HTML button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.close();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a user control as your popup and that you're adding it to a grid you can use this

`((this).parent as (Grid)).remove(this);`

Or you can show some code and I can create a better answer.